# F#: downcast a discriminated union

Tags: casting, f#, downcast, discriminated-union

I have a discriminated union type:

```
type F =
| A of int
| B of float
```

Suppose I have a list of F that has been filtered to yield only objects of type A:

```
let listOfAs=list.filter (fun f -> match f with | A(f') -> true | _ -> false)
```

How can I work with the resulting list of F without requiring pattern matches everywhere in my code?  The compiler doesn't like a direct cast, eg

```
list.map (fun f -> int f) listOfAs
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot really cast discriminated union value - the type of `F` is a different thing than the type `int` (it is not like C union where they have the same binary representation).

So, the easiest solution is to write a function that takes `list<F>` and returns `list<int>` containing only the `int` values that were wrapped in the `A` case.

To do this, you can use `List.choose` (instead of `List.filter`). This lets you specify a projection where you can return `None` (meaning skip the value) or `Some v` (meaning return value `v` as part of the resulting list):

```
let listOfAs = List.choose (fun f -> 
  match f with 
  | A(f') -> Some f'
  | _ -> None)
```

Comment: On a side note, the code can be shortened by one line by replacing `fun f ->` with the `function` keyword and removing the `match` line.

Comment: Yes, it can be :-) I do not usually do this when showing code because it requires explaining two things at once!